# CAS Spnego - KrbException: Checksum failed

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, cas, spnego

I'm trying to use SPNEGO (Kerberos) authentication with Active Directory - with CAS server ([github](https://github.com/apereo/cas)).
Here is official instruction: https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/SPNEGO-Authentication.html

I used this template: https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template
So `pom.xml`is taken from there.

Unfortunately, I only receive this exception:

```
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
jcifs.spnego.AuthenticationException: Error performing Kerberos authentication: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.processKerberos(Authentication.java:447)
        at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.processSpnego(Authentication.java:346)
        at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.process(Authentication.java:235)
        at jcifs.spnego.Authentication$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c5958df9.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at jcifs.spnego.Authentication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84bb5e21.process(<generated>)
        at org.apereo.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JcifsSpnegoAuthenticationHandler.doAuthentication(JcifsSpnegoAuthenticationHandler.java:60)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticateAndResolvePrincipal(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:174)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.lambda$null$3(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:129)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticateInternal$4(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.authenticateInternal(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:124)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:140)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$12a86894.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
        at org.apereo.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:45)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:32)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:46)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:32)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:45)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:32)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:46)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:32)
        at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5085e4b0.authenticate(<generated>)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationTransactionManager.handle(DefaultAuthenticationTransactionManager.java:34)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.handleAuthenticationTransaction(DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.java:55)
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.handleInitialAuthenticationTransaction(DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.java:41)
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.resolver.impl.InitialAuthenticationAttemptWebflowEventResolver.resolveInternal(InitialAuthenticationAttemptWebflowEventResolver.java:69)
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.resolver.impl.AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.resolve(AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.java:475)
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.resolver.impl.AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.resolveSingle(AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.java:480)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy164.resolveSingle(Unknown Source)
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.AbstractAuthenticationAction.doExecute(AbstractAuthenticationAction.java:59)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.DecisionState.doEnter(DecisionState.java:51)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:105)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.launchExecution(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:263)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:28)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apereo.cas.security.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apereo.cas.security.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:64)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at jcifs.spnego.Authentication$ServerAction.run(Authentication.java:517)
        at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.processKerberos(Authentication.java:430)
        ... 274 more
Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
        ... 280 more
Caused by: KrbException: Checksum failed
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 283 more
Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decryptCTS(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decrypt(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256.decrypt(Unknown Source)
        ... 289 more
```

**Question:** 
What does it means? Which configuration element could make this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. In short: I have bad `cas.authn.spnego.jcifsServicePrincipal` in `cas.properties`.

**Details:**

- Active Directory
- JDK 1.8 + JCE
- Apereo CAS 5.1
- Tomcat 8.5.15 on Windows Server 2012 R2

CAS [documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#spnego-authentication) suggest such configuration:

```
cas.authn.spnego.jcifsServicePrincipal=HTTP/cas.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

But be aware, that `jcifsServicePrincipal` is *principal* name - the name of the Active Directory **user**, which has SPN assigned.
I have user `cn=service_xxx` which has `servicePrincipalName` attribute assigned to `HTTP/machine1.domain.com` and `HTTP/machine1` (but I think, that only first is needed).

It's worth to follow this tutorial: [Kerberos / SPNEGO based SSO (Single Sign-On) in Weblogic](http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.in/p/weblogic.html).

**How does my CAS works:**

Using above tutorial, I create SPN for the existing user *service_xxx* (user which may log into *machine1*):

```
setspn -s HTTP/machine1.domain.com  service_xxx
```

User *service_xxx* has such properties in Active Directory: AES 128 bit encryption and AES 256 bit encryption.

Both operations were done by Active Directory administrator (he has sufficient privileges).

So `service_xxx` is principal name (user name) and `HTTP/machine1.domain.com` is only SPN attribute assigned to the principal. As far as I understood - now CAS server running on machine `machine1.domain.com` (this is machine URL) can obtain any information from AD (LDAP) by user `service_xxx`. So CAS server can also authenticate any user using Kerberos protocol. In my opinion, this is why the CAS property `jcifsServicePrincipal` should point to principal `service_xxx@domain.com` (full principal name with @domain.com) and not to its SPN attribute name (unless they are equal strings).

**My configuration details:**

1. Principal with AES attributes and SPN attribute set
2. Java with *Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength* installed
3. Keytab created using `ktab.exe` tool from JDK
4. `login.conf` file - the same as in [CAS documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/SPNEGO-Authentication.html)
5. `cas.properties` and `krb5.conf` as shown below

**Keytab**

Key tab creation procedure (no any special privileges require):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\ktab.exe" -a service_xxx -n 0 -k cas.keytab
```

`-k` specifies key tab output file name. `-n 0` specifies KNVO number. Disclaimer: for my user cn=service_xxx in Active Directory there is no attribute `msDS-KeyVersionNumber` (KNVO), so I used 0. But I think that Windows ignores the KNVO number - see [this comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/601270/retreive-the-current-kerberos-kvno-from-active-directory#comment711624_601270).

One more information about **keytab**:

A lot of tutorials and even official [documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/SPNEGO-Authentication.html) suggest to make keytab using `ktpass.exe`. Unfortunately this requires AD admin privilege, so this is not a good idea. Better use `ktab.exe` from JDK (as above). You only need to remember always generating new keytab after `service_xxx` password change.

To test key tab there several options:

- use kinit to gather kerberos ticket (for service_xxx principal). This is also tool supplied by JDK.
- Try this small app written by @Ivan Veselovsky from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13859217/5162026

**`cas.properties` which works for me:**

```
cas.authn.spnego.kerberosConf=/etc/cas/config/krb5.conf
cas.authn.spnego.jcifsServicePrincipal=service_xxx@domain.com
cas.authn.spnego.loginConf=file:/etc/cas/config/login.conf
cas.authn.spnego.kerberosRealm=DOMAIN.COM

cas.authn.spnego.principal.principalAttribute=sAMAccountName

cas.authn.spnego.ldap.ldapUrl=ldap://path.to.ldap.domain.com 
cas.authn.spnego.ldap.baseDn=DC=domain,DC=com #this is base dn where LDAP starts searching for users
cas.authn.spnego.ldap.bindDn=cn=SERVICE_XXX,DC=domain,DC=com #it's a kind of login to LDAP
cas.authn.spnego.ldap.failFast=false
cas.authn.spnego.ldap.subtreeSearch=true
cas.authn.spnego.ldap.useSsl=false
cas.authn.spnego.ldap.searchFilter=cn={host}
```

It is funny that paths like `/etc/cas/config` works also on Windows and points to `C:` drive root - so `C:\etc\cas\config`. Be aware, that all config here (and at all Java files) paths are using forward slash.

I also supply krb5.conf. This file is specific to your organization. Often you can find it somewhere inside `C:\Windows` folder in any workstation connected to domain. So you can copy it, and edit as you want. You can also write it by hand (sample is in CAS Documentation).

The most important is to add there path to keytab:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_keytab_name = C:/Users/SERVICE_XXX/my_keytab/cas.keytab
```

As you can see - `default_keytab_name` parameter is under `[libdefaults]`. The same path is also inside `login.conf` file (see Apereo CAS documentation).

If you enable debug in CAS (`cas.authn.spnego.kerberosDebug=true` and change debug level inside `log4j2.xml`). Then you should see when CAS is using your keytab, something like:

```
2017-07-04 19:56:29,613 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JcifsSpnegoAuthenticationHandler] - <Processing SPNEGO authentication>
Java config name: /etc/cas/config/krb5.conf
Loaded from Java config
Found KeyTab Default keytab
Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): DOMAIN.COM
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): SERVICE_XXX
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 79; type: 18

// ... edited

Added key: 23version: 0
Added key: 16version: 0
Added key: 17version: 0
Added key: 18version: 0
```

Otherwise, you will see that CAS `Looking for keys for: service_xxx@domain.com` and then throws exception similar to below.

**Troubleshooting 1:**

If you see exception similar to this one:

```
Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
        ... 280 more
Caused by: KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 283 more
```

it's very likely, that you have wrong path to `.keytab` file (as pointed also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44762883/5162026)).

**Troubleshooting 2:**

If CAS complains about not supported encryption:

```
Encryption type AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96 is not supported/enabled
```

it's likely that Java JCE isn't installed or Java was updated and in the result JCE support was overwritten by update (install JCE again).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i had to set up the property javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true in my CATALINA_OPTS

The CAS (version 5.2.x) uses jcifs.spnego, this one uses this property (Authentication class, decompiled Line 414, sorry i did not find the source code) in order to use (or not) the service account credentials to connect.

Comment: This is also true for CAS 6.2.x. And thanks, your post saved me a lot of time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

for my case, its the SPN needs to be set up.